# Django template filter dynamically by model field

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following code:

```
# main.html

<div class="ingest">
    {% includes "checklist.html" with is_ingest=1 %}
</div>

<div class="master">
    {% includes "checklist.html" with is_master=1 %}
</div>
```

-

```
# checklist.html

{% if is_ingest %}
    {% for option in checklist_options %}
        {% if option.is_ingest %}
             do something
         {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% if is_master %}
    {% for option in checklist_options %}
        {% if option.is_master %}
             do something
         {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Is there a way to simplify the code, so I can pass a variable like:

```
    {% for option in checklist_options %}
        {% if option.*VARIABLE* %}
             do something
         {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

How would I do this so I don't have to repeat my self so many times? (In the actual code I have to repeat the above pattern 5 times.)

Comment: I think you should resolve it in view-side. please, show my an example of your view and models. Maybe you can make some query and avoid avoid  some `if`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i think you can resolve it in view-side. I dont know your views, but I give an example:

```
def checklist_options(request):
   # I dont know how you get your query
   checklist_options = CheckOption.objects.all()

   #I dont know where it comes from
   is_master = True
   if is_master:
      masters_checklist_options = checklist_options.filter(is_master=True)

   #I dont know where it comes from
   is_ingest = True
   if is_ingest: 
      ingest_checklist_options = checklist_options.filter(is_ingest=True)

   return render(request, ' main.html', {
       "masters_checklist_options": masters_checklist_options
       "ingest_checklist_options": ingest_checklist_options
   },)
```

So, your main.html can be:

```
<div class="ingest">
    {% includes "checklist.html" with collection=ingest_checklist_options %}
</div>

<div class="master">
    {% includes "checklist.html" with collection=master_checklist_options %}
</div>
```

and checklist.html:

```
{% for option in collection %}
     do something
{% endfor %}
```

What do you win?

You let your login in views (it should be in models, maybe).

You avoid the n+1 problem when you call `{% if option.is_master %}`, as an example.
Because in each rendering of check_list.html, you already had filterer the `is_master` or `is_ingest` options.

I hope you undestand my point, i've guessed you models and give you a fool view example.
If you need help, show us your view and models, and i'll be able to help you more.

Hope helps